# How to obtain the path in which a file is residing in instead of getting the path to the debug folder?

Tags: c#, wpf, directory, path

I'm Currently inside a for loop which iterates through a set of folders and obtains some required values from a JSON file. I also want to get the absolute path to each of those files.

Currently I tried approaches such as

> string currentDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory; string
>   currentDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

Both of these gave me location to the debug file

what I want is the location of the Folder in which this file is existing rather .

Below is the code segment to which I hope to include this new code.

> string rootDirectory = fbd.SelectedPath;
>
> var foundFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(rootDirectory,
>   "server.config", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
>
> foreach (var file in foundFiles)
>                   { RepositoryHomeSettingsModel repositoryHomeSettingsModel =
>   JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText(file));
>
> string Name = SettingsModel.name;
>
> }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below possible ans,Do you require the same ?

```
var foundFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(rootDirectory, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            foreach (var file in foundFiles)
            {
                var folderpath= Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
                //RepositoryHomeSettingsModel repositoryHomeSettingsModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText(file));

                //string Name = SettingsModel.name;

            }
```